# AWS Batch output to Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

When using Step Functions, Lambdas can get input from a state and create output that can be used by the Step Functions to affect flow using a Choice state. However, while Batch jobs can also get input from Step Functions, I can't find information on how to get batch output back to Step Functions to be fed into a Choice state (as in JSON output, rather than simply the succeeded/failed state of the job).

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for a while and I think the answer is no, you can not get a batch output or response into a step function directly. The only way to do it that I know about is to write your batch response to s3/dynamodb or some other storage location and then access that is a subsequent step in the step function.